# $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial\mathbf{x}^\top} = \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial\mathbf{x}}^\top$ in denominator layout?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

In the denominator layout (also called Hessian formulation), we have that

$$\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{y}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \begin{bmatrix}
        \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial \mathbf{x}} & \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial \mathbf{x}} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial y_m}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
    \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
        \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1} & \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_1} & \dots & \dfrac{\partial y_m}{\partial x_1} \\
        \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_2} & \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_2} & \dots & \dfrac{\partial y_m}{\partial x_2} \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_n} & \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_n} & \dots & \dfrac{\partial y_m}{\partial x_n} \\
    \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}, \tag{1}$$

where $ \mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_n \end{bmatrix}^\top \in \mathbb{R}^n $ and $ \mathbf{y} = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 & y_2 & \cdots & y_m \end{bmatrix}^\top \in \mathbb{R}^m $, and the gradient matrix given by

$$\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \mathbf{X}} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_{11}} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_{12}} & \dots & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_{1n}} \\
    \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_{21}} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_{22}} & \dots & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_{2n}} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_{m1}} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_{m2}} & \dots & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_{mn}} \\
   \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}. \tag{2}$$

where $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{X} = \left[x_{ij}\right] \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

I have noticed that a special case of the gradient matrix is when $m=1 \therefore \mathbf{X} = \mathbf{x}^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$, where $\mathbf{x}= \left[x_{i}\right] \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Substituting it in the equation (2), we have

$$\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \mathbf{x}^\top} = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_{1}} &
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_{2}} &
\cdots &
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_{n}} \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \tag{3}.$$

However, from the Equation (1), when $\mathbf{y} = y \in \mathbb{R}$ is a scalar, it is true to state that

$$\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \begin{bmatrix}
        \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_1} \\
        \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_2} \\
        \vdots \\
        \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_n}
    \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \tag{4}$$

Hence, I have concluded that $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \mathbf{x}^\top} = \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \mathbf{x}}^\top$. Is that right?

Comment: Your question boils down to whether or not $\vec{x}$ is naturally identified with $\vec{x}^T$. This is only true when we make the identification $\vec{x}^T$ and $\vec{x} \cdot $, where $\cdot$ is the usual dot product. In settings where we don't assume the dot product or have any scalar product between vectors, we must carefully distinguish row ($\vec{x}^T$) and column ($\vec{x}$) vectors.

Comment: To maybe more explicitly answer your question, we should identify $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bf{x}}$ with a row-vector and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bf{x}^T}$ with a column-vector. Roughly, this is because $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bf{x}}$ naturally acts *on* column vectors (think of the Taylor expansion $f(\bf{x} + \bf{y}) = f(\bf{x}) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bf{x}} (\bf{y}) + \dots$). $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bf{x}^T}$ naturally acts on row vectors (though I know of no canonical examples).

Comment: If you like $\bf{x}$ switches from being a column vector to a row vector in $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bf{x}}$ so that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bf{x}}$ and $d\bf{x}$ can "cancel" as fractions.There is no natural operation of column vectors on each other (outside of the context of an scalar product), but there is a natural operation of row vectors on column vectors (matrix multiplication).

Comment: @CharlesHudgins "This is because $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mathbf{x}}$ naturally acts on column vectors". It is not necessarily true, at all. It depends whether you are using Jacobian or Hessian formulation.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins "To maybe more explicitly answer your question, we should identify $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}}$ with a row-vector and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}^\mathsf{T}}$ with a column-vector.". Well, as I have demonstrated, both are column vectors for Hessian for formulation, aren't they?

Comment: I'm not aware of the distinction between those two different formulations (my understanding is that it's standard to consider $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bf{x}}$ a row-vector). In any case, my comments apply mutatis mutandis. Though it is arbitrary whether $\bf{x}$ is a row or column vector, once we have made that choice, it is *not* arbitrary whether or not $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bf{x}}$ should be a row or column vector. $\bf{x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bf{x}}$ must be dual to each other: if one is a row vector the other must be a column vector and vice versa.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins What you are saying is absolutely wrong, c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

Comment: @CharlesHudgins the main point is: It depends on which representation you are using. There are two main representation: denominator layout (also known as Hessian formulation), and numerator layout (also known as Jacobian formulation).

Comment: In my case (Hessian formulation), I am trying to prove that $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial\mathbf{x}} = \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial\mathbf{x}^\mathsf{T}}$. It seems right to me, but I am just want to make sure.

Comment: The statement is trivially true if you identify $\bf{x}$ and $\bf{x}^T$. If you don't, then it's only true if you have a metric tensor and have chosen coordinates in which the matrix of the metric is the identity. I don't know which part of my comments you consider absolutely wrong, but "Though it is arbitrary whether $\bf{x}$ is a row or column vector, once we have made that choice, it is not arbitrary whether or not $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bf{x}}$ should be a row or column vector" is true to my knowledge. But yes, the initial choice is a matter of convention as I said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140081/discussion-between-rubem-pacelli-and-charles-hudgins).